# redux toolkit can't bring the value from my action

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I try to dispatch an action that will return a value of stored in the asyncStorage,
its a react native  project , and I am using redux toolkit , I don't know why its always returning
the initialized value of the state, user always null , could ypu please help , here is my code :

```
//store
    export const store = configureStore({
      reducer: {
        myuser : userAuth
      },
    })

===============

    import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
    
    const initialState = {
    user: null,
    isError: false,
    isSuccess: false,
    isLoading: false,
    message: '',
  }

    export const getUser = createAsyncThunk('userlog/getUser',   ( thunkAPI) => {
        return  AsyncStorage.getItem('myuser')
        .then((data) =>  data )
        })
    
    export const userSlice = createSlice({
      name: 'userlog',
      initialState,
      extraReducers : (builder) =>{
          builder.addCase(getUser.pending , state =>{
            state.isLoading = true
          })
          builder.addCase(getUser.fulfilled , (state, action) =>{
            state.user = action.payload
            state.isLoading = false
          })
          builder.addCase(getUser.rejected , state =>{
            state.isLoading = false
          })
      }
    
    })
    
    export default userSlice.reducer
```

and in my app.js that's how I am dispatching the action :

```
import {getUser} from '../../app/features/user/userSlice'


  const { user, isLoading, isError, isSuccess, message } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.myuser
  )

   useEffect(()=>{          

    dispatch(getUser())
})
```

Comment: the issue was I forgot to import asyncstorage

Answer (score 0):

destructure your getUser in props like this

```
 const { user, isLoading, isError, isSuccess, getUser , message } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.myuser
  )
```

Comment: your code crashes the app thanks for ur help

Comment: gave this code before you edited the question. your welcome.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

with useSelector you are trying to get state values from user.myuser which I don't see in your state

try

```
  const { user, isLoading, isError, isSuccess, message } = useSelector(
    (state) => state
  )
```

or

```
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.user)
```

for getting the user

edit after added sourcecode to question:
there is a mismatch between the name of the key in your store and the name in creacte slice. in the store it's called myuser and in createSlice it's called userLog. You should change userLog to myuser

Comment: please see my edited question I forgot to add sore code to it

Comment: there is a mismatch between the name of the key in your store and the name in creacte slice. in the store it's called myuser and in createSlice it's called userLog. You should change userLog to myuser

Comment: I have renamed userlog , now its  myuser too but still user is null , by the way asynsctorage contains data 
@Jelte Homminga

Comment: what is userAuth you pass to configureStore, is it the reducer (userSlice.reducer)?

Comment: import userAuth from './features/user/userSlice' , and rejected addCase I ve made isError to true , and when I console.log (isError)  after dispatching the ation it says true, that's mean its rejecting

Comment: userlog/getUser in createAsyncthunk should probably be myuser/getUser

Comment: i ve changed it , still not working , I have removed  the content of my action (getUser) and I made it simply returning a string and it worked now console.log(user) => 'kkk' that 's mean issue is in asyncstorage code

Comment: the issue was I forgot to import asyncstorage , its was a rdiculos error , usually in these scenerios iy should fire an error saying you must import asyncstorage from somewhere , but here it did not happen